# Erro consulta PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query, pdo

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
@$import = $dbconn->prepare("UPDATE t SET");

if(a <> "")
{
$import .= "teste2= '$a', teste= '$b', ";
...
```

Ele retorna este erro:

> ```
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in
> ```

O erro é na linha em que concateno a variavel a query, Quando rodo a query no banco funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que seria algo +/- assim, você pode concatenar texto com texto e não texto com objeto...

```
$import = "UPDATE t SET ";

if(a <> ""){
  $import .= "teste2 = '$a', teste= '$b' ";
}

$dbconn->prepare($import);
```